# Deploy Go backend HTTP API in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, httpbackend

I would like to communicate a nextjs application deployed at Vercel to a HTTPS API backend in golang that is deployed in AWS ECS. I am thinking of architecture without a load balancer to minimize the project cost.

Can I expose an API in an ECS container just using an API Gateway?

I am glad for any response that figures out if it is possible or even provides a link for a tutorial or other guides for possible solutions.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to route http gateway requests directly to ecs without a load balancer in the middle .   if you really want to minimize project cost, use a lambda function, not a persistent container in ECS.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution. Just using an Ec2 instance with Nginx and reverse proxy.
Does not need API gateway nor load balancer and for a dev env, it works like a charm. For production, the recommended way is to set the API gateway with a loader balancer.